# Russian babel, lmodern, and sans-serif font

Tags: beamer, babel, sans-serif, latin-modern

If I have three things in my file that apparently conflict with each other.

1. `\usepackage[russian]{babel}`
2. `\usepackage{lmodern}`
3. `\sffamily` in the body of the document.

As a result, I don't get a sans-serif font as expected. Instead, I get a serif font. It seems that all three components are necessary to create this effect. If I don't load `lmodern` or if I load `babel` with the `american` option, I do get a sans-serif font.

The origin of this problem is the following. I am trying to use bold fixed-width (teletype) font in `beamer`. I've read that to get bold fixed-width font I need `lmodern`, but when I include it the whole document becomes serif instead of sans-serif, which is the default.

I am using TeX Live 2013 on Ubuntu. Here is a MWE, which incorrectly produces a serif font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Latin Modern doesn't support Cyrillic. There are not many choices for a monospaced font in TeX Live 2013 featuring boldface and supporting Cyrillic.

You can do it with PTMono, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{PTMono}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\lipsum[2]

\raggedright\ttfamily
\lipsum[3]

\bfseries\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
Москва

\sffamily Москва

\ttfamily Москва

\bfseries Москва
```

as document body you get

[image]